# wso2 api manager modify JSON payload sent to backend

Tags: json, url, wso2, wso2-api-manager, mediator

I have REST API URL defined as

`https://hostname/[version]/[service]/[operation]`

and I would like to transform JSON payload in WSO2 API Manager in order to put version and operation inside.

So the WSO2 will send it to backend in the following form:

```
POST https://backend/[service]
{
    “version”: [version],
    “operation”: [operation]
}
```

So I need to put version and operation from URL to JSON payload. How to do it?

Comment: there are several options - so you want to send the operation and version along the original payload or instead of it?

Comment: I would like to send it along the original payload. So the original payload would be appended with operation and version.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to create a new payload and POST with values from the resource URI definition (not API context).

Lets assume:

- you don't want to change the method (the resource is having POST method).
- the original request posted is JSON as well

You may want to create a (synapse) mediation flow as for ESB building such a message.

Plugging in the mediation is described in the documentation [Adding Mediation Extensions](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+Mediation+Extensions). This mediation will be executed for every request of the API

Having resource `https://hostname/[version]/[service]/[operation]`

In the mediation, you may build the JSON payload

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
  <format>{
      "version":"$1", 
      "service": "$2", 
      "some_original_data": "$3"
    }</format>
  <args>
    <arg  expression="get-property('uri.var.version')"/>
    <arg  expression="get-property('uri.var.service')"/>
    <arg  expression="$.person.name" evaluator="json" />
  </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Comment: I am trying to do it on `https://hostname/01.00/test/myoperation` and I will always get `version` and `service` as empty string. Are you able to advice what could be wrong? The mediation flow is exactly like described in your post and `version` and `service` are defined as parameters in API context definition. It seems that the payloadFactory is not able to see its values through argument expression...